# Optional Principal Key in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a relationship I set up in EF Core. It's actually a view that I use and don't need tracking.

The two tables are `Employees` and `PositionRoles`. The primary key in `Employees` is the `EmployeeID`. But I also want to join on the `PositionCode` and include that entity. However some `Employees` don't have a `PositionCode` so it's null.

This was working until an `Employee` with a null `PositionCode` showed up.

Is this even possible or do I have to either set the `PositionCode` to a value for the dataset or use Linq to do left join queries instead of `.Include()`?

```
builder.Entity<Employee>()
       .ToView("Employees")
       .HasMany(u => u.PositionRoles)
       .WithOne()
       .HasForeignKey(r => r.PositionCode)
       .HasPrincipalKey(u => u.PositionCode);
```

Employee Class:

```
   public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        etc...
        public IEnumerable<PositionRole> PositionRoles { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<TeamRole> TeamRoles { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<UserLocation> UserLocations { get; set; }
}
```

Position Role:

```
    public class PositionRole
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PositionCode { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PositionDecode { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; }
    }
```

When an employee has a null PositionCode I get an error:

```
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')

at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindValue(TKey key) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean updateDuplicate) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.AddOrUpdate(InternalEntityEntry entry) at
```

This is because when pulling my employee I have an Include(e => e.PositionCode). My question is, since this is a principal key and not primary key can I use it this way? Or if there's any other way to do this relationship.

Comment: Can you show us the model classes for `Employee` and `PositionRoles` ?

Comment: `HasMany(u => u.PositionRoles).WithOne()` is a 1:n relationship and the rest of the mapping is for a 1:1 realtionship. This is very unclear.

Comment: I've added the entity classes. Yes It's a 1:n relationship but since it's a principal key and not a primary key can it be optional?